# How to access a parent element from iframe using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I am working on a website in `asp.Net`, and i am using `iframe` to load a separate page.
The separate page named `Districting.aspx`, includes an `asp button`, which `onClick()`, calls a function in c#, named `DoneClicked()`.
This is the asp button control:

```
<asp:Button ID="LinkButtonDone" CssClass="button button-yellow" runat="server" OnClick="DoneClicked" Text="Done" />
```

In code behind, the DoneClicked function:

```
protected void Doneclicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some code here
        // Calling a function from Default page
    }
```

What I need to do is at the end of `DoneClicked` function, a function from the `Default.aspx` page must be called.

So how can I access a function from `Default.aspx.cs` in the iframe page code behind?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Below It Worked for me

In Code Behind

```
protected void Doneclicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "scriptid", "window.parent.location.href='ParentPageName.aspx';", true);  
 }
```

Comment: @Aristos/@Divya Rana/@Hanady : Can anyone of you please explain me how the above solution worked to call a method from Default.aspx.cs file (Parent page)

Comment: @C.M.W. you actually NOT call a method, you just write some javascript code on page renders that calls it - or run what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access it directly (at least not in an advisable fashion).

You should abstract out the common code from Default.aspx into a class somewhere that can be used by both pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that direct, but you can do it indirect using javascript.

So you make a hidden button on the default page that can call the `DoneClicked` function as:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <asp:Button ID="Done" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="DoneClicked " />
</div>
```

and inside the `iframe` where `Districting.aspx` is loaded, you can call the "DoneClicked" by clicking the button using javascript as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.parent.document.getElementById('Done').click();
<script>
```

Note that the `ClientIDMode="Static"` because from the other page you can not know what is the rendered id, so keep it static. If you do not use dot net 4 that have the static id, then you need to also use javascript to send the rendered id to the page, or some other way to locate the button.

Also note the `window.parent.` that "can see" from the iframe the DOM structure of the controls of the page that contains the iframe.